# Can I skip the final boss cutscene?

Tags: sonic-mania

Every time I die against Sonic Mania's true final boss [Phantom King](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Phantom_King)/[Kleptomobile](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Kleptomobile), I'm forced to rewatch the cutscene of Eggman and The Heavy King duking it out for the Emerald.

While the cutscene was fun to watch the first time, it gets a bit annoying to sit through on repeated attempts.

**Is there any way to skip the cutscene before the true final boss?**

Comment: As far as I know, the answer is no.